# How to read parts

Tags: sef

I have a problem with this program: I was able to make another draft program but it only reads the first three lines and stops. Unfortunately, the input file is not symmetrical so I should use while loops for some parts only to avoid repeating parts of the program. With strcpy I could copy the work done up to a certain point and then continue from that point on. I was trying but visual studio tells me to move the memory to the heap but I don't know how to do it ... Practically I should only extrapolate certain data from the input file and order them in an output file according to a precise line.
I also know there's a problemi with char buf[200], rec[200] because I have to allocate much more memory...

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I don't know to change what i've done...

Comment: Use `while (1)` or `for (;;)` and `break` the loop if one of the `fscanf`s returns something  diiferent to 1

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: start checking  with the debugger what happens when you use `buf` uninitialized.

Comment: @David Ranieri I'll try what you suggested ... As far as memory allocation is concerned, how can I do it? Should I use malloc?

Comment: No, you don't need dynamic memory, since you are writing to a file a buffer large enough will suffice, but you should initialize your objects before reading them. I want to help but I'm not able to see a pattern in your source file :(

Comment: Thank you again, I published a pattern of the source file , for example "session 1 (COPY MODE):
number of sequences: 15
 
registration 1:
characters given: CALOR
 
registration 2:
characters given: CARINO" you don't see it?

Comment: Hope you can help me now ahaha

Comment: The problem is that you don't follow the same rules in the sections, you want COPY MODE or ONLINE_FREE_MODE?  you want given or recognized? You need a more solid design, `fscanf` has poor regex support.

Comment: @David Ranieri the problem is that the input file is exactly that one, as I said unfortunately it isn't symmetrical so I have to do different loops during the scan. So I think I should save what the fscan does up to a certain point with strcpy and they start a new loop from that point forward to scan a new section...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216514/discussion-between-sandra-boccia-and-david-ranieri).

Comment: the duplicate is wrong for me, the problem is not about `feof` but how to extract the data from the non regular file

Answer (score 0):

the first time in

> ```
> while ( !feof(fd) ) {
>   fscanf(fd, "session %d (COPY MODE):\n\n", &session);
> ```

you call `feof` before any read so `feof` cannot work proprely, an easy change is to do

```
while (fscanf(fd, "session %d (COPY MODE):\n\n", &session) == 1) {
```

Out of that the mode can be something else that `COPY MODE` and the two `\n` after are not mandatory, you also do not check your next `fscanf` success and globaly the algorithm you use is wrong

A possible way to do the job also checking the validity of the input file is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fp = fopen("summary.txt", "r");
  
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("cannot open summary.txt");
    exit(1);
  }
  
  int session;
  char mode[64];
  const char * separator = "_____________________________________________";
  
  while (fscanf(fp, " session %d (%[^)]):", &session, mode) == 2) {
    if (strcmp(mode, "COPY MODE") && strcmp(mode,"ONLINE FREE MODE")) 
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "invalid file, invalid mode '%s'\n", mode);
       exit(1);
    }

    char line[64];
    char given[64];
    char recognized[64];
    int registration, registration_set = 0;
    int sequences, sequences_set = 0;
    
    for(;;) {
      /* read next line, bypass possible newline(s) before */
      if (fscanf(fp, " %63[^\n]", line) != 1) { 
        if (!feof(fp)) {
          perror("reading file");
          exit(1);
        }
        *line = 0;
      }
      else if (sscanf(line, "number of sequences: %d", &sequences) == 1) {
        sequences_set = 1;
        continue;
      }
      else if ((*given == 0) && 
               (sscanf(line, "characters given: %63s", given) == 1)) {
        if (!registration_set) {
          fprintf(stderr, 
                  "registration is missing before 'characters given: %s'\n",
                  given);
          exit(1);
        }
        if (!sequences_set) {
          fprintf(stderr, 
                  "sequences is missing before 'characters given: %s'\n",
                  given);
          exit(1);
        }
        continue;
      }
      else if ((*recognized == 0) &&
               (sscanf(line, "characters recognized: %63s", recognized) == 1)) {
        if (!*given) {
          fprintf(stderr, 
                  "given is missing before 'characters recognized: %s'\n",
                  recognized);
          exit(1);
        }
        continue;
      }
      
      if (registration_set) {
        if (!*given) {
          fputs("invalid file, given is missing\n", stderr);
          exit(1);
        }
        printf("%d %d %d %s %s\n", session, registration, sequences, given, recognized);
        
        if (!*line || !strcmp(line, separator))
          break;
      }
      
      if (sscanf(line, "registration %d:", &registration) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "invalid file, 'registration <n>:' expected rather than '%s'\n",
                line);
        exit(1);
      }
      else {
        registration_set = 1;
        *given = *recognized = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Note the space at the beginning of the format of the `fscanf`, that allows to bypass character considered to be space including the newline

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat summary.txt 
session 1 (COPY MODE):
number of sequences: 15
 
registration 1:
characters given: CALOR
 
registration 2:
characters given: CARINO
 
registration 3:
characters given: SUSHI
 

_____________________________________________
session 2 (COPY MODE):
registration 1:
number of sequences: 15
 
characters given: SUSHI
characters recognized: SUSHI
 
_____________________________________________
session 3 (ONLINE FREE MODE):
number of sequences: 15
 
registration 1:
 
characters given: PERA
characters recognized: PFRA
 
registration 2:
 
characters given: SALON
characters recognized: SALON
 
registration 3:
 
characters given: PERRO  
characters recognized: PERRO
 
_____________________________________________
session 4 (ONLINE FREE MODE):
 
registration 1:
number of sequences: 7
 
characters given: TORTUGA
characters recognized: TORTUGA
 
registration 2:
number of sequences: 4
 
characters given: ANAEROBIO
characters recognized: ANAERPBIO
 
registration 3:
number of sequences: 4
 
characters given: PAPELES
characters recognized: PAPELEX
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 1 15 CALOR 
1 2 15 CARINO 
1 3 15 SUSHI 
2 1 15 SUSHI SUSHI
3 1 15 PERA PFRA
3 2 15 SALON SALON
3 3 15 PERRO PERRO
4 1 7 TORTUGA TORTUGA
4 2 4 ANAEROBIO ANAERPBIO
4 3 4 PAPELES PAPELEX
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you just make it more simple please? It's a bit difficult for me to understand it all...

Comment: @SandraBoccia it can be a little simplified removing the tests checking the input file is correct, anyway to do that is not a good idea, I encourage you to *always* check the validity of the inputs

Comment: @SandraBoccia why did you edited my answer to remove the part compilation & execution ? (I rejected your edit) And why did you also edit your question to remove a large part of it ? (I rollback)